# Qt 5.5 not binding to port

Tags: linux, qt, udp, bind

I have some code which worked fine in Qt 5.9 under Windows but is causing issues with Qt 5.5 under Linux.

It's basically contacting an echo server to detect whether a device is on the network and it starts by setting up a UDP sender and receiver, after which it sends a packet and checks that it comes back.

The problematic bit seems to be in binding the receiving socket:

```
// Create the two sockets.

m_sendSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
m_recvSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);

// Connect sending socket to other end.

m_sendSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress(host), 43837);

// Bind receiving socket so it will receive any response.

bool x = m_recvSocket->bind(m_sendSocket->localPort());
std::cout << x << " " << m_sendSocket->localPort() << std::endl;
```

It creates the two sockets (outgoing and incoming) then attempts to bind the outgoing socket's local port to the incoming socket's receiving port (so the response can be picked up).

This works fine under the Windows environment but the `bind` is failing under Linux. Since all it returns is a boolean value, I'm at a loss as to *why* it's failing.

Thinking it may be the default binding mode for the platform, I also tried explicitly setting that so that Linux would match Windows:

```
bool x = m_recvSocket->bind(m_sendSocket->localPort(), QAbstractSocket::ShareAddress);
```

But that didn't help.

The local port for the sender socket seems okay, I've seen values like `38349`, `58597`, and `37433`.

Does anyone know why this might be failing, or whether Qt makes more information available somewhere as to *why* it's failing, or whether there's a better way to do this (that won't fail)?

Comment: Are you running it as normal user? Maybe try as `root`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get further information from the socket by accessing `m_recvSocket->errorString()`. In your case, modify the `cout` line to be:

```
std::cout << x
    << " " << m_sendSocket->localPort()
    << " " << m_recvSocket->errorString().toStdString()
    << std::endl;
```

What you'll see is something along the lines of "address already in use" because, as you realise, Windows and Linux have different default binding modes - the former is a more sharing OS whereas the latter appears to be vindictive and possessive <sup>(a)</sup>.

So the *sending* socket has effectively locked up the local port it's using when calling `connectToHost()`, meaning the receiving socket cannot bind to it.

The way to solve this is to have the sending socket bind explicitly with the sharing option before connecting to the host. This can be done with:

```
m_sendSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
m_recvSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
m_sendSocket->bind(0, QAbstractSocket::ShareAddress);
m_sendSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress(host), 43837);
bool x = m_recvSocket->bind(m_sendSocket->localPort(), QAbstractSocket::ShareAddress);
std::cout << x
    << " " << m_sendSocket->localPort()
    << " " << m_recvSocket->errorString().toStdString()
    << std::endl;
```

That results in the output:

```
1 47334 Unknown error
```

on my system, the error text can be ignored since the return value of `bind` was true (the initial `1` on the output line).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Pax ducks for cover :-)